# Test all values in a boolean[]

Tags: java, arrays

I'm wondering if there is a more 'neat' way to test if all the values in a boolean array are true/false than iterating through the array and testing each individually like this:

```
for (boolean eval:booleanArray) {
    if (!eval) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Essentially, i want to see if all of the values stored in an array of booleans is true, and if so, perform an action.

I'm pretty sure that there is some form of method for this, like `array.contains(false)` but i may be wrong.

Comment: It was a hastily thrown together example to illustrate the point but thanks

Comment: provide more context, how is this used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Guava:

As pointed out by SotiriosDelimanolis

```
// verify all values are true
boolean result = !Booleans.contains(myArray, false);
```

Old post...

```
boolean result = Iterables.all(
         Booleans.asList(myArray),
         Predicates.equalTo(true));
```

Using statics it becomes:

```
boolean result = all(asList(myArray), 
                            equalTo(true));
```

Another options is using Sets

```
boolean result = Sets.newHashSet(Booleans.asList(myArray)).contains(true);
```

Comment: Cool solution, non-standart to say the least!

Comment: @DenisKulagin LOL, and you think *my* method was complicated?  You amuse me.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis incorrect. Works just fine. Java takes care of the cast to `Boolean[]` for you. Just tried it to be sure. NP.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. My Bad. I updated the post to use `Booleans.asList`

Comment: Also, if you're using `Booleans`, you can just use its `contains` method.

Comment: Wow! Duh! 6 more to go

Answer (score 1):

Use the `List` interface.  It works thanks to the magic of autoboxing.

```
List<Boolean> values = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
// ...populate it ...
if(values.contains(false)) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Converting to a List<> and wrapping primitives in a Boolean to do such a simple thing. No way)

Comment: @DenisKulagin You should never be using primitive arrays to begin with.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Right you are.  Forgot about primitive vs. object array casting, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely the fastest. And if you would like to *neatinize* it - extract to a separate method.

```
public static boolean testAllTrue(boolean[] booleanArray) {
  for (boolean eval : booleanArray) {
    if (!eval) {
        return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Nice in that it doesn't incur the cost of casting to `Boolean` as other solutions. Just pass in `boolean expected` as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Java8:

Some other ways:

```
long falseCount = Arrays.asList(arr).stream().filter(e -> !e).count();
```

If `falseCount` is 0, it means everything is true.

Or `allMatch`

```
boolean allTrue = Arrays.asList(arr).stream().allMatch(e -> e);
```

But using this system means:

1. Arrays.asList => Create a list, copy everything in the list
2. Wrap primite types to reference types (boolean -> Boolean)

Your foreach method, is the best method but if you already have items in a List why not use this?

Comment: Big assumption that OP is using Java 8

Comment: Yes, but since other already have said the right solution why not be a bit creative with alternative solutions?

Comment: Would have just suggested a comment in your post that stated that solution required Java 8. The OP is obviously new to Java to ask this question.

Comment: Oh, while i was writing this answer i added "If you use Java8" but i deleted it for error.. Thanks.

Comment: Assuming `arr` is a `boolean[]` this solution won't work in 7 or 8.

Comment: It works only if it is a Boolean[] right.

Comment: I'd ask you to add that detail in your answer.

Comment: You should add this as an answer to the duplicate question.